# Controller not calling the View in Rails ,  is Sample

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.2

1 - My controller is this , but this not call the view whit this name is login.html.erb, im not understand beacause what happen this , is to show the form of the login.

```
class FinancesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /finances
  # GET /finances.json
  def login
    @user = User.find_by_name(params[:user])
    if @user
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      redirect_to login_url
    end

  end

  def index
    @finances = Finance.all(:order => "created_at")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @finances }
    end
  end
```

2 - Someone can talk to me to use the authenticate method to validate a sample login whit user and password forms some, can show to me how use this method , the find_by_name_and_password dont works.

I thanks by the answers, many.

Routes.rb

```
Controle::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'login' => 'finances#login' 
  resources :finances
end
```

Comment: What is your controller name? and where are you putting the `login.html.erb` file? What error are you getting?

Comment: the controller name is 'finances' and the login.html.erb is inside the finances patch whit the others views generate by scaffold.My error is in the navigator whit the error "redirect wrong" , i read and this is because the action enter in a infinite loop.My route is    `resources :finances
  match '/login' => 'finances#login'`

Comment: have you included the `login` action to your `config/routes.rb`file? Make sure to include it and restart the webserver before proceeding.

Comment: I rebooted the server but not changed.Obrigado pela ajuda que ta dando ^^,falar ingles pra ajudar se alguém tiver mesmo problema que eu.

Comment: No problem! please paste your `config/routes.rb` file too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check for the `@user` object.

because, as of your code it will redirect to your `login` method if `@user` is not available.

To render `login.html.erb` from `login` method, there is no need for any manual redirections.

Comment: Thanks is some remove this     `else
      redirect_to login_url` from the controller and the view login rendering ,very very thanks ^^.